# On Fourier expansions of Siegel automorphic forms

Tags: reference-request, automorphic-forms

Please tell me references on Fourier expansions of (non-holomorphic) automorphic forms on the symplectic group of matrix size > 2. I can find formulas of "Fourier coefficients'' of non-holomorphic Eisenstein series in some notes, but I can't find  the "Fourier expansion'' related to those.

Moreover I'd like to know differences of the Fourier expansion via the Whittaker functions, that via the Jacobi functions, that via Bessel functions.

Thanks in advance.